# Restore sqlite database in xamarin forms or xamarin android

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I implemented backup database in xamarin and it copies my database to sdcard. The code below shows path of backup file:

```
"/sdcard/MyTaskDatabase"
```

I want to implement restore backup. And to do that I want to copy the backup file to the path below (local database path):

```
database = new TodoItemDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "TodoSQLite.db3"));
```

i know that i must use this function:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);
```

but I can't fetch the sourcePath and destinationPath.
Please help.

I have a function to restore db but it doesn't work and doesn't have error.

```
public void CopyAndRestore(string sourcePath)
    {
        var dbFileName = "TodoSQLite.db3";

        TodoItemDatabase yourSQliteRepository = new TodoItemDatabase(GetLocalFilePath(dbFileName));

        string destinationPath = GetLocalFilePath(dbFileName);

        yourSQliteRepository.DeleteAllDatabase();
        yourSQliteRepository.CloseDb();

        System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath, true);
    }
```

Comment: do you mean that you literally don't know what paths to use for those two arguments?  Or that you have tried it and are getting an error or it just doesn't work?

Comment: @Jason I tried it and it didn't work, Can you fix that?

Comment: it doesn't work and it doesn't generate any error?  How are you testing if it works or not?  Are you sure your are closing any open SQL connections before overwriting the existing db file?

Comment: @Jason I updated my question and attached my restore function to it, please look at that, can you tell me mistake?